# Select a single record on basis of Group By "Having"

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

[image]

**I have a table say "T1"** from which I have to select only one record which has been **last updated by any user.** The expected result should be somewhat like :-

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the most recent DATETIME for each transaction (based on comments in response to another answer), you actually want to be able to retrieve more than just one record - you want to retrieve one for each group of transactionID:

```
SELECT transactionID, userID, MAX(updatedDateTime) AS MostRecent
FROM T1
GROUP BY transactionID
```

This works with test data that includes additional transactionIDs. I'll add a SQLFiddle if the site will work for me . . .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT X.* FROM T1 X
WHERE X.updatedDateTime=(SELECT MAX(updatedDateTime) FROM Temp WHERE temp.userID = T1.userID)
```